# How to search in array of array of object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose the mongodb document(table) 'users' is

```html
{
    "_id": "6065923bc5d509071857f6e6",
    "version": [
        {
            "name": "1.1.0",
            "status": "not Approved",
            "_id": "606592b1c5d509071857f6e7",
            "files": [
                {
                    "_id": "606592b3c5d509071857f6e8",
                    "url": "https://google.com/1.png",
                    "status": "awaiting"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "606592b8c5d509071857f6e9",
                    "url": "https://google.com/2.png",
                    "status": "awaiting"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the status of  this "***[https://google.com/1.png***"](https://google.com/1.png***%22) image
Can we do using findOneAndUpdate?  because i want to return the updated Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to search for the `awaiting` status for the collection `users`

```
db.users.find({"version.files.status":"awaiting"}).pretty()
```

It will automatically search within the arrays.

Updating, however, is a bit different and you should use [arrayFilter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
db.users.updateOne(
  {
    "version.files._id": "606592b3c5d509071857f6e8",
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "version.$[version].files.$[file].url": "something else",
    },
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "version._id": "606592b1c5d509071857f6e7" },
      { "file._id": "606592b3c5d509071857f6e8" },
    ],
  }
);
```

Make sure to have an index on your `find` query:

For the above example

```
db.users.createIndex({"version.files._id":1},{background:true})
```

Many more example available on the [Mongo Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

---

EDIT

As per your comment, here is a working example:

```
db.users.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "version.files._id": "606592b3c5d509071857f6e8" },
  {
    $set: {
      "version.$[version].files.$[file].url": "Test URL",
      "version.$[version].files.$[file].status": "Test status",
    },
  },
  {
    returnNewDocument: true,
    arrayFilters: [
      { "version._id": "606592b1c5d509071857f6e7" },
      { "file._id": "606592b3c5d509071857f6e8" },
    ],
  }
);
```

[image]

Comment: can we do using findOneAndUpdate() ??

Comment: Of course, just replace the updateOne by findOneAndUpdate and use the `returnNewDocument: true` boolean to return the updated doc (alongside arrayFilters) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Yes working.. but when i update "status" of file in that case "STATUS" is not updating
I am using this
 {
        $set: {
          "version.$[version].files.$[file].status": data.status,
          "version.$[version].files.$[file].url": data.url
        }
      },

Comment: Yes, you need to provide **all** the fields you want to update in the **$set** object

Comment: You need to add `returnNewDocument:true` as well

Comment: but instead of  **returnNewDocument:true**  this am using **new: true**  actually _returnNewDocument:true _ not working in my code... i already share you my API Code..
and when i am using **new: true** it return new document and in that new document only updated URL is showing. and i check the DB to.. only URL is updating
can you please rewrite my above query ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    await db.collection('users').updateOne(
        { _id: users._id },
        { $set: { "version.$[version].files.$[file].url": "newStatus" } },
        {
            arrayFilters: [
                { "version._id": "606592b1c5d509071857f6e7" },
                { "url": "https://google.com/1.png" }
            ]
        }
    );
```

Edit:

If there's more than one record with `"https://google.com/1.png"` It'll update the status of the first record it encountered.

Edit2:
Thanks callmemath for fix my mistake