# How to assign the same id to multiple objects in mongoose?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I want to assign the same id value to `roomID` where the objects have the same type.

```js
const Item = new Schema({
  roomID: { type: String},
  type: { type: String }
});

const Order = new Schema({
  items: [{ type: Item }]
});
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```js
{
  id: "1234567890",
  items: [
    {
      roomID:"5efd1db1803ec01b1c590e23"
      type: "first",
      // more data
    },
    {
      roomID:"5efd1db1803ec01b1c590e23"
      type: "first",
      // more data
    },
    {
      roomID:"5efd1db1803ec01b1c590e82"
      type: "second",
      // more data
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search in array of array of object in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915728/how-to-search-in-array-of-array-of-object-in-mongodb)